# How to write all items on same line in the csv file python

Tags: python

My code is like this:

```
F = open('words.csv', 'w') 
F.write(words + n1 + n2 )
```

Here words, n1, n2 are the lists of items.

But the output in the CSV file is like this:

```
Hi 6
1376
Hello 39
697
Nihao 30
396
```

My question is how to write all the items on the same line, e.g.,

```
Hi 6 1376
Hello 39 697
Nihao 30 396
```

Thank you.

Comment: You are just writing a regular text file with a .csv extension, not a true .csv file.  You should also show the actual values of words, n1 and n2 if you want an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply [**rstrip**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.rstrip) the `"\n"` from `n1`:

```
F = open('words.csv', 'w') 
F.write(words + n1.rstrip() + n2 )
```

---

```
>>> n = "6\n"
>>> n.rstrip()
'6'
>>>
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) , it words

Comment: @BobbyZhao no problem, if this answer helped you feel free to accept it by clicking on the green check to notify the community you have found an acceptable answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `writerow` in csv library:

```
import csv

with open('words.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    rows = zip(words, n1, n2)
    for row in rows:
        csvwriter.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

```
tempList = zip(words, n1, n2)
for line in tempList:
    F.write(reduce(lambda x, y: str(x)+" "+str(y), line))
```